# Click all checkboxes on website

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, click

I have (in Excel, VBA) a sub that will navigate to this webpage:

http://www.nordea.dk/wemapp/currency/dk/valutaKurser

And copy the quoted rates. However, I would like to remove all the rates, and only add the ones my sub needs.

To do this, I need to check all of the boxes (to the left in the table), but the number of boxes is not constant - so I can't hardcode the boxnames.

I suppose one way to this is to extract the entire html, determine the number of rows, and then loop. But it seems very unhandy. Surely there is some smatter way, which requires less code and less storage?

Comment: Hm, that may be tricker than you'd like for VBA - have you looked into [importing data](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708f2249-9569-4ff9-a8a4-7ee5f1b1cfba) from a webpage? Here's another page that might help: [here](http://www.internet4classrooms.com/excel_import.htm).  If that works, it might be easier to create a macro that imports the data, then you can resume your other macro to parse out data and keep only what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Split()` the table by `vbNewLine` and search for the currency in each row of the set (**mind the headers**).
Since the inputs are named like *table:body:**rows:2**:cells:1:cell:check* you can match the currency with the checkbox.
In practice it looks like (up to getting the element names):

```
Function FirstRow(myArray() As String, Optional curr As String) As Long
If curr = "" Then
    curr = "*[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*"
Else
    curr = "*" & curr & "*"
End If

For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    If myArray(i) Like curr Then 'FX denoted as "XXX/XXX"
        FirstRow = i
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i
End Function
Sub ert()
Dim myArray() As String, URLStr As String
URLStr = "http://www.nordea.dk/wemapp/currency/dk/valutaKurser"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.Navigate URLStr

Do Until (ie.readyState = 4 And Not ie.Busy)
    DoEvents
Loop

On Error GoTo Err:
Data = ie.Document.body.innerHTML 'innerText

If False Then
Err:
    Data = ie.Document.body.innerHTML
End If

myArray = Split(Data, "<tr>") 'vbNewLine) 'vbCrLf)

'For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
'    Cells(i + 1, 1).Value2 = myArray(i)
'Next

Dim curr() As String
ReDim curr(2)
    curr(0) = "DKK/NOK"
    curr(1) = "EUR/SEK"
    curr(2) = "USD/CHF"
For i = LBound(curr) To UBound(curr)
    x = FirstRow(myArray, curr(i)) - FirstRow(myArray) + 1
    MsgBox "table:body:rows:" & x & ":cells:1:cell:check"
Next i
ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm sorry, the `vbNewLine` won't cut it this time, my bad. Also, checking a named element shouldn't be that hard, had you provided your snipplet for checking all the boxes I would have even given it a shot.

Comment: Made an update, it's still a sketch (doesn't have e.g. error handling if currency is not found) but will give you a helping hand if hardcoding the box names is your other alternative.

Comment: Of Course if you split the HTML by rows you can also search for the `input name=` string in the same block to give you the prima facie input name, the sky is the limit.